# Can I use the Android 4 HttpResponseCache with a WebView based application?

Tags: android, caching, webview

I'm working on a WebView based app that's currently running on v3.1 tablets. I don't seem to be able to get the WebView to cache css, js and images (or use the cache). The app always seems to connect to the server, which is returning a 304 response (HTML pages are dynamic and always need to use the server).

I was wondering if the HttpResponseCache (available under v4) works with a WebViewClient, or whether the WebView should already manage the caching of HTTP resources.

Thanks.

Comment: You may have a look at this backport of ICS HttpResponseCache if you need to use it in Android 2.x: https://github.com/candrews/HttpResponseCache

Answer (score 4):

After some test, I figured out that the Android layer of Webkit does not use URLConnection for HTTP request, that means HttpResponseCache cannot be automatically hooked into WebView as other native scenarios.

So I tried an alternative approach: use a custom WebViewClient to bridge WebView and ResponseCache:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(final WebView view, final String url) {
        if (! (url.startsWith("http://") || url.startsWith("https://")) || ResponseCache.getDefault() == null) return null;
        try {
            final HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            final String content_type = connection.getContentType();
            final String separator = "; charset=";
            final int pos = content_type.indexOf(separator);    // TODO: Better protocol compatibility
            final String mime_type = pos >= 0 ? content_type.substring(0, pos) : content_type;
            final String encoding = pos >= 0 ? content_type.substring(pos + separator.length()) : "UTF-8";
            return new WebResourceResponse(mime_type, encoding, connection.getInputStream());
        } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); return null;
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); return null;
        }
    }
});
```

When you need offline access to cached resources, just add a cache header:

```
connection.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-stale=" + stale_tolerance);
```

BTW, to make this approach work properly, you need to correctly set your web server to response with cache-enabled "Cache-Control" header.

Comment: Is there a way to tell if the response came from cache?